# what is variant member in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++. I read very frequently from some sites that variant member?.

```
class School
{
  int x; -> data member. 
}
```

I know data member. but what is variant member ?

NOTE:
From the c++ specification: Under Constructor page.

```
X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor.
```

Comment: Can you post a link to one of these sites?

Comment: Stack Overflow itself is one of them.

Comment: Are you talking about `boost::variant` or something? Traditionally, a variant is a union containing all supported types.

Comment: You might be looking for `union` or `boost::variant<>`

Comment: +1 I hate people downvoting others for no apparent reason. Anyone with some c++ knowledge can quickly reply with both possible answers to his question. Newsflash: not everyone is born a C++ expert and people start out confused unable to phrase questions correctly and clearly.

Comment: Hassan Syed. Thanks and Well said.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Variant member" is defined in 9.5/8 of C++11:

> A union-like class is a union or a class that has an anonymous union
>   as a direct member. A union-like class X has a set of variant members.
>   If X is a union its variant members are the non-static data members;
>   otherwise, its variant members are the non-static data members of all
>   anonymous unions that are members of X.

In other words, all the non-static data members of a union are "variant members", and for a class containing any anonymous unions, their non-static data members are "variant members" of the class.

The context that you quoted is 12.1/5, saying that if a union-like class has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor, then the default constructor of the class itself is deleted. The problem is *which* variant member should be constructed by the default constructor of the class, and the solution is not to have a default constructor. If all variant members have trivial default constructors there's no problem, since by doing nothing the default constructor of the class is constructing all/none of them equally.

`boost::variant` is a separate thing. I wouldn't be too surprised if "some sites" say "variant members" when they mean "the possible types that a given `boost::variant` can hold", that is to say the "members" of that `variant`. But that's not the meaning newly-defined in the C++11 standard.

Comment: Steve,thanks for the reply. Trying to get more clarity from your comment. So to say  union { int x; int y }, in this, both x, y are the variant members. Am i correct?

Answer (score 7):

The term *variant* is usually employed to identify a member that can hold a value of a set of different types. Similar to a `union` in the language, the term `variant` is usually reserved for types that allow the storage of the different options in a type safe way.

You might want to read over the documentation of the boost variant library for one such example, and if that does not clear up the concept, drop a comment/create a question with your doubts.

[Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/)

Answer (score 3):

A variant is a structure containing a union member and an unsigned integer member that describes which member of the union is currently being used. If you don't know what a union is, read about it first, and then come back.