# A function with variable return type

Tags: c++, function, return-type

I want to be able to make a function `GetInput()` which takes a class as a parameter, and returns whatever is input. The function definition would look like this:

```
GetInput(class type) {
    if (type == string) {
        string stringInput;
        cin >> stringInput;
        return stringInput;
    }
    else if (type == int) {
        int intInput;
        cin >> intInput;
        return intInput;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I don't know what to write for the return type of the function because it can be either string or int. How can I make this function work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is variant member in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525964/what-is-variant-member-in-c)

Comment: Do you know about templates? Is there a reason you do not want to use a template for this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have not learned templates

Comment: If you make `type` an actual type instead of a variable by passing it as a template parameter this can be done. Also look at `if constexpr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make it an actual argument, but you can do something similar by creating a *function template* (also called a template function):

```
template<class T>
T GetInput() {
    T input;
    cin >> input;
    return input;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
string stringInput = getInput<string>();
int intInput = getInput<int>();
```

`getInput<string>` and `getInput<int>` are considered different functions, generated by the compiler - hence why this is called a template.

Note - if you're using multiple files, the whole template definition must go in a header file and not the source file, because the compiler needs to see the whole template in order to generate functions from it.

Comment: You can define templates in source files just fine, it's declaring them in headers that is problematic.

Comment: @nwp we are talking about C++ templates right? Implementing then in the header files are the only portable way

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot No it's not. `template <class T> void f(){} int main() { f<int>(); }` is a perfectly correct and portable C++ program with a template in a source file.

Comment: @nwp ah I see. note that immibis said "if you're using multiple files ..."

Comment: Note the question shows the function returning `NULL` and doing nothing else if the type is not `string` or `int`. This can be done with a general template that returns `NULL` and specializations for `string` and `int` that read and return an item. Except `NULL` is not a proper value for most classes, so something else has to be worked out for the return value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed, I assumed the intention was to expand it for more types when needed.

Answer (score 0):

As you've described it, you can't get it to work.

However, since the caller needs to know what type is being read, the simple solution is to use a templated function.

```
#include <iostream>

//   it is inadvisable to employ "using namespace std" here 

template<class T> T GetInput()
{
    T Input;
    std::cin >> Input;
    return Input;
}
```

And to use

```
//   preceding code that defines GetInput() visible to compiler here

int main()
{
     int xin = GetInput<int>();
     std::string sin = GetInput<std::string>();
}
```

The templated function will work for any type `T` for which input streams (like `std::cin`) support streaming and that can be returned by value.    You can use various techniques (traits, partial specialisation) to enforce constraints (e.g. produce a meaningful compilation error if the function is used for a type for which the function logic does not work) or to provide different functionality for different types.

Of course, since all you're doing is reading from `std::cin`, you could actually read directly

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int xin;
    std::string sin;

    std::cin >> xin;
    std::cin >> sin;
}
```